# Shopify FriendBuy app javascript illegal token issue

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am using the FriendBuy app for a shopify store at this moment and am running into an issue where an illegal token is being caught, aside from that there are no other issues that I can see. What I am trying to do is activate the referral via a text link. I have followed the documentation according to the app to the letter, but after running a javascript validation test on the code a number of errors popped up. I find it hard to believe an expensive app with a huge user base would fail on something simple so the issue must be on my end but I can't seem to discover where. The code creating the issue is

```
       window['friendbuy'].push(['widget', ‘xx-xxx’, {configuration: {share_button:false}}]);
```

according to the documentation this is what i should use, replacing xxx-xxx with the campaign id. The only inconsistency I can see is that the suggested x's to fill are 5 characters long, where the actual code is 6, but that is what I came up with after following the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your javascript has Microsoft quotes around the ‘xx-xxx’. If you change them to 'xx-xxx' it should work.

Corrected example below:

`window['friendbuy'].push(['widget', 'xx-xxx', {configuration: {share_button:false}}]);`